# Other words in the construction "that's a me (problem/thing)"

Tags: word-request, informal-language

Recently I have come across the construction "that's a me problem", which I found kind of interesting. Doing some googling I have found some variations such as "that's a you problem" and "that's a we problem". I have also found "that's a me thing".

I am wondering, are there words other than "problem" and "thing" used in this construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not run across any, but I can imagine hearing "That's a me job" or "That's a me baddie" or "That's a me issue" or "That's a me question".

I would know what the speaker meant.

Comment: ok, but for me there is a big difference between (1) it is actually a phrase which is commonly used in informal English or (2) whether one might be able to intuitively understand what is meant but it is not a phrase which is usually used. For the latter, I would not recommend using it. Your answer seems to imply it is ok.

Comment: @SybillePeters I think it's closer to your (1) than (2), I might say "very informal" and expect it only in speech, not writing.